# Bootstrap Tabs not working after adding Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, turbolinks

Here is my show page -

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active.text-center{style: "width: 50%"}
    %a{:href => "#project_details"} Details
  %li.text-center{style: "width: 50%"}
    %a{:href => "#project_analysis"} Project Analysis
```

Here is my application.js -

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
.. other scripts
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-select
.. other scripts
//= require turbolinks
//= require turbolinks-compatibility
```

Head content of App -

```
%html
  %head
    %meta{content: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1", name: "viewport"}/
    %title REOM
    = Gon::Base.render_data
    %link{href: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/
    %link{:href => "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700", :rel => "stylesheet"}/

    = stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    - if javascript_exists?(controller_name)
      = javascript_include_tag controller_name
    = stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

Before adding Turbolinks, Tabs were working perfectly, but now when I click the other tab, the page reloads and shows the content of the first tab.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to go in this exact order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require turbolinks-compatibility
# other scripts
```

Comment: It didn't make any change.

Comment: anything in the js console?

Comment: No, nothing in console

Answer (score 0):

try add the option to your `<a>` tag

```
data: { turbolinks: false }
# data-turbolinks: false
```